# How to use my computer's internet connection in Raspberry Pi?

Tags: networking, ssh

I have connected my desktop computer (running Ubuntu 16.04) to my Raspberry Pi through a router (ethernet connection).
My computer can access internet with USB tethering from my phone.
I can SSH to the Raspberry Pi, but it cannot connect to internet.

`ping google.com` says `ping: google.com: Temporary failure in name resolution`

`sudo apt update` says `Temporary failure resolving 'raspbian.raspberrypi.org'`.

How to forward my computer's internet connection to Raspberry Pi?

The router is only connected to the desktop and the Raspberry Pi.

Comment: you must enable internet access sharoing on the desktop (i don't remember how to do it with the NetWorkManager of old 16.04) It should be quite simple to achieve :: desktop runs dhcp and add the route (ie acts as a router for the Pi)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I directly connected the Raspberry Pi to my computer through ethernet, and connected a monitor to the Pi. Then I ran `ifconfig` in the Pi to get its IP address (it was `10.42.0.38`, maybe this is the default?)

Then I sshed to the RPi from my desktop, and now it is connected to the internet. However, this does not solve the issue when RPi is connected to a router and there is no way to connect a display.

Answer (score 2):

On the Raspberry Pi, enter this command:

```
sudo ip route add default via xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
```

where `xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx` is your desktop computer's IP address.

Your RPi already knows where your local network is. This command tells the RPi that there is a route to all *other* IP addresses (a *default* route) and it goes through your Ubuntu machine.

You may need to set DNS name servers as well.

Comment: Does not work. The RPi still does not connect to the internet